# Integration of product of two Gaussian

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

Suppose having three correlated (multivariate) normal variables $A, B, C$, each of them's mean and (co)variance can be noted as $m_A, m_B, m_C$ and $\Sigma_A, \Sigma_B, \Sigma_C$ respectively.

Is it possible to obtain an analytical expression for the following operation?
$$\int p(A|B, C)p(B)dB$$

I know one could get the conditional distribution of $p(A|B, C)$ by making use of Gaussian identity (e.g., Eq. 5d of [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eroweis/notes/gaussid.pdf) by regarding $B, C$ as one joint multivariate normal), but I am not sure if/how this would be helpful for the expression given above.

Details: so to try to make it more explicit,
Let $[B, C]^T\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\left[\begin{array}{cc} m_B\\m_C \end{array} \right], \left[\begin{array}{cc} \Sigma_B, \Sigma_{BC}\\\Sigma_{CB}, \Sigma_{C} \end{array} \right]\right)$. With the mentioned Gaussian identity: $A|[B, C]^T \sim \mathcal{N}\left(m_A + \Sigma_{A[BC]^T}{\left[\begin{array}{cc} \Sigma_B, \Sigma_{BC}\\\Sigma_{CB}, \Sigma_{C} \end{array} \right]}^{-1}\left[\left(\begin{array}{cc} B\\C \end{array} \right) -\left(\begin{array}{cc} m_B\\m_C \end{array}\right)\right], \Sigma_A - \Sigma_{A[BC]^T}{\left[\begin{array}{cc} \Sigma_B, \Sigma_{BC}\\\Sigma_{CB}, \Sigma_{C} \end{array} \right]}^{-1}\Sigma_{[BC]^TA}\right)$
Substitute the above into the integration, this explicitely can be written as
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
\int \left((2\pi)^{-d_{A}/2}\text{det}\left(\Sigma_A - \Sigma_{A[BC]^T}{\left[\begin{array}{cc} \Sigma_B, \Sigma_{BC}\\\Sigma_{CB}, \Sigma_{C} \end{array} \right]}^{-1}\Sigma_{[BC]^TA}\right)^{-1/2} \text{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(A - m_A - \Sigma_{A[BC]^T}{\left[\begin{array}{cc} \Sigma_B, \Sigma_{BC}\\\Sigma_{CB}, \Sigma_{C} \end{array} \right]}^{-1}\left[\left(\begin{array}{cc} B\\C \end{array} \right) -\left(\begin{array}{cc} m_B\\m_C \end{array}\right)\right]\right)^T{\left[\Sigma_A - \Sigma_{A[BC]^T}{\left[\begin{array}{cc} \Sigma_B, \Sigma_{BC}\\\Sigma_{CB}, \Sigma_{C} \end{array} \right]}^{-1}\Sigma_{[BC]^TA}\right]}^{-1}...\right)\right) \cdot (2\pi)^{-d_B/2} \text{det}(\Sigma_B)^{-1/2}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2}(B - \mu_B)^T{\Sigma_B}^{-1}(B - \mu_B)\right)dB
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This looks quite cumbersome to move forward even if we merge the det term and the exponential term respectively.

Comment: definitely possible. probably you will get better help if you write down the integral you wish to solve explicitly, then show what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: many thanks @kevinkayaks for the comments. have put the problem in an explicit form hoping to get more hints.